# Getting swf boolean parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, parameters, loaderinfo

I have a swf that I call as

/SWFUploader/upload.swf?single=true

Then in ActionScript 3 I read in the value. But it's not working. Here's my test code (the first block is taken from http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html ):

```
var keyStr:String;
var valueStr:String;
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
for (keyStr in paramObj) {
    valueStr = String(paramObj[keyStr]);
    trace(keyStr + " = " + valueStr);
}

var isSingle:Boolean = this.loaderInfo.parameters.single as Boolean;
var isSingle1:Boolean = this.loaderInfo.parameters['single'] as Boolean;
var isSingle2:Boolean = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters['single'] as Boolean;
var isSingle3:Boolean = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.single as Boolean;
trace(isSingle + ", " + isSingle1 + ", " + isSingle2 + ", " + isSingle3);
```

And frustratingly this is the resulting two lines that are traced:

```
single = true
false, false, false, false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, it's a casting problem. If I replace some of the above code with String in place of Boolean the traces all come out "true". So my question may well be just: How do I cast the parameter value String:"true" to Boolean:true in ActionScript (and why doesn't it happen anyway)?

Comment: if you want to get the type of an variable try this `trace(typeof(isSingle));`

Comment: Thanks mgraph, that's a useful piece of ActionScript for debugging this kind of problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ActionScript not empty and not null String is casted to Boolean `true`.

```
var singleStr:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.single;
var singleBool:Boolean = singleStr == "true";
```

Comment: That second line is not really a cast, but it works so that's great. Thanks.